# iOS : Scanning barcode very slow

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode, swift4, google-vision

I am developing scanning barcode application using swift4.

I have tried using 2 popular open source , those are [MTBarcode](https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner) (using AVFoundation) and [iOS Vision](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision) (using GoogleVision Framework), but scanning speed is not fast as I expect, it takes about 2 or 3 seconds to detect real barcode.

Some people suggest me change sessionPreset to AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium but it is not effective.

Anyone can suggest me how to improve scanning speed. Should we update another camera configuration or use another open source ?

Comment: What kinds of barcodes are you scanning? I've used the built-in AVMetadataOutput for EAN-8 and EAN-13 and found it to be extremely reliable and fast.

Comment: Not sure if any of those already do it, but forcing focus may help a lot, as often a lot of the time is just lost trying to acquire focus rather than the actual barcode identification. Beyond that, you’ll have to provide a lot more details, include the type of barcode, its size, distance, the type of material, whether you have good contrast, etc. The actual phone used may also help. And of course we suppose you use the back camera.

Comment: @jcaron : barcode which I want to scan is Code 128 type. Size is about 1cm x 4cm. I tried with iphone 6 , 6s and 5. I think I have tried adjust camera constrast, but scanning speed is not faster. Could you show me how to force focus directly on barcode?

Comment: @ThangBM Facing same issue. barcode scanning is slow. Whats the solution?

Answer (score 3):

What helped me speed up barcode scanning was setting `sessionPreset`property of `AVCaptureSession` to high:

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.sessionPreset = .high
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

You can also try out [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/read-barcodes). It worked really fast when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

i have did QRCode and BarCodeScanner i'll share the snippet below

```
import AVFoundation
```

add delegate

```
class YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER: UIViewController,AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
```

initialize required variables

```
    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?
    var qrCodeDelegate:QRCodeScannerVCDelegate?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
```

add below function into your viewController

```
   func startVideoCapture(){
        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.qrCodeView.bounds
            self.qrCodeView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            self.qrCodeView.clipsToBounds = true
            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

//            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
//                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
//                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
//                self.qrCodeView.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
//                self.qrCodeView.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
//            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            print("No QR/barcode is detected")
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            if barCodeObject != nil{
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
            }

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                print("\(metadataObj.stringValue)")

            }
        }
    }
```

and in your `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.startVideoCapture()
}
```

and don't forget to check camera permission before call startViewCapture

Hope this will help you

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for focus mode, I have to move camera to acquire focus, barcode always lost focus

Comment: you mean overlay or autofocus?

Comment: I mean I want camera autofocus barcode quickly. In some scanning barcode application, it focuses on barcode very quickly.